How do I output code that uses `import` rather than `require` from the typescript compiler (so that node can run it)?
I'm trying to compile a script in typescript and run it with node importing a module. Feels like it should be the simplest thing in the world, no? But I'm running into issues.
The .js file tsc produces uses require but my version of node seems to demand that I use import rather than require. Returning the following error:
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/alex/all/.obsidian/plugins/sample/node_modules/remark/index.js from /home/alex/all/.obsidian/plugins/sample/render_test.js not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in /home/alex/all/.obsidian/plugins/sample/render_test.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/alex/all/.obsidian/plugins/sample/render_test.js:3:16) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}

I have no tsconfig.json.
Code to reproduce error
// render_test.ts
import { remark } from 'remark'

remark.parse(`

# Hello world

`)

npm install typescript
npm install remark
npm install node
npx tsc render_test.ts
npx node render_test.js

Here is the .js file generated.
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
var remark_1 = require("remark");
remark_1.remark.parse("\n\n# Hello world\n\n");

npx node --version
v20.18.1

npx tsc --version
Version 5.7.2

What I've tried
I've done a reasonable amount of googling. And found a few pages like this and some related questions that spoke about adding "type": "module" to package.json and changing the module compiler option in tsconfig.json but I couldn't get this to work.
On thing that seemed to work is changing the extension from .ts to .mts, this then produced a  mjs file that node should run. Feels like a weird work around though.
Some relevant questions:

What is the difference between .js and .mjs files?
The difference between "require(x)" and "import x" (This seems to be the cause of the problem - node has updated to use the same standard as ES6 - but tsc has to be cajoled into producing this)
Is CommonJS 'require' still used or deprecated?

type: "module"
Adding this to package.json produces the following output to the .js. file which still uses require.
"use strict";
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
// render_test.ts
var remark_1 = require("remark");
var result = remark_1.remark.parse("\n\n# Hello world\n\n## Heading two\n\nWe are here.\n\n");
console.log(result);

Trying to run this with node produces an error related to exports:
file:///home/alex/all/.obsidian/plugins/render_test/render_test.js:2
Object.defineProperty(exports, "__esModule", { value: true });
                      ^

ReferenceError: exports is not defined in ES module scope
This file is being treated as an ES module because it has a '.js' file extension and '/home/alex/all/.obsidian/plugins/render_test/package.json' contains "type": "module". To treat it as a CommonJS script, rename it to use the '.cjs' file extension.
    at file:///home/alex/all/.obsidian/plugins/render_test/render_test.js:2:23
    at ModuleJob.run (node:internal/modules/esm/module_job:234:25)
    at async ModuleLoader.import (node:internal/modules/esm/loader:473:24)
    at async asyncRunEntryPointWithESMLoader (node:internal/modules/run_main:122:5)

Node.js v20.18.1


have you tried using ts-node instead?

I tried ts-node it says SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

and you have added type: module inside your package.json?

does it work when you try import from a clean project?

No, I have already extracted this to a clean project: no tsconfig.json just one file and one dependency.

type: module still uses require, but it also adds and "exports" line which node errors out on (I've added details to the answer above)

within the compatibility section of remark, it's written they try to keep the latest version compatible with Node.js 16.Have you tried using Node.js 16?
